# Disconnect lancom vpn connection

Tags: vpn

How can I kill a special vpn connection within ssh session on my lancom router?

```
# show my active connections
ls Status/VPN/Connections

# I try something like ...
set Status/VPN/Connections/MyConnection2Destroy ???
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use lanmonitor, right-click the connection, done.

Comment: yep, but unfortunately that's not a scriptable approach